# How do I see the text when the text box is really small?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject that I added a Canvas. In this Canvas I have a Text UI element.

The text is not visible, or it may be too blurry to see. (it may be really small)

How do I fix this?

I have best fit selected.

Here is an image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to the blurriness is doing the following:

Set the `X`, `Y` **scale** from the inspector to a lower number like `0.2` or even `0.02`

Set the **font size** to larger number like `[100, 200]` depending on the scale you previously selected.

Expand the text area from the game view so the text is visible **or** change the overflow property of the text.